# SQLite, Python and lists

Tags: python, list, sqlite, iterator

I am a newbie to Python and SQLite but I have a program where I want the user to enter how many items they want to order from a database table. They enter the products and quantities and the select query should return the items that match. It works except that it only prints out the last user entry and not all the user entries. I think the problem is around the select query line but I cannot figure it out. I have tried numerous variations but it either crashes or returns just the last user entry.

```
enter code here
for i in range(orderQty):
    prodItem = int(input("Enter your Item to the List: "))
    userOrder.append(prodItem)
    prodQty = int(input("Enter the item quantity: "))
    userQty.append(prodQty)


for j in range(len(userOrder)):
    cursor = connection.execute("SELECT GTINnum, Item, CurrentStock,Cost from orderFile WHERE GTINnum= ?", (prodItem,))


    for row in cursor:
        print ("GTINnum =", row[0], "Item = ", row[1], "Cost = ", row[2], "Qty Ordered=",(prodQty), "\n")
        prodCost = prodQty * row[2]
        print ("Total product cost is: ", (prodCost))
```

Comment: indentation still not ok. Please use your editor to indent your code by 4 spaces and then paste into question. Makes life much easier ;)

Comment: try `userOrder[j]` as parameter for the select instead of `prodItem`. Similar for `prodQty` further down. Take `userQty[j]` instead.

Comment: IDLE tells me indentation is 4 spaces?

Comment: userOrder[j] throws a ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

Comment: try the code from the answer pls

Comment: Still getting ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type    cursor = connection.execute("SELECT GTINnum, Item, CurrentStock,Cost from orderFile WHERE GTINnum= ?", (userOrder[j]))
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

Comment: missing a comma after `userOrder[j]`...

Comment: Yes it seems to work although it now just prints out the first row  in the loop row in cursor. Only iterating once?

Comment: you select for a single value of the key, so each select will result in one hit. The iteration over the user's input is in the for loop enclosing the select.

Comment: many thanks I get it now and will keep working on this.

Comment: feel free to accept the answer below ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the block

```
for j in range(len(userOrder)):
    cursor = connection.execute("SELECT GTINnum, Item, CurrentStock,Cost from orderFile WHERE GTINnum= ?", (prodItem,))
    for row in cursor:
        print ("GTINnum =", row[0], "Item = ", row[1], "Cost = ", row[2], "Qty Ordered=",(prodQty), "\n")
        prodCost = prodQty * row[2]
        print ("Total product cost is: ", (prodCost))
```

you are using the last user input `prodItem`and `prodQty` over and over. Replace by something that is iterating thru the lists you have built before:

```
for j in range(len(userOrder)):
    cursor = connection.execute("SELECT GTINnum, Item, CurrentStock,Cost from orderFile WHERE GTINnum= ?", (userOrder[j],))
    for row in cursor:
        print ("GTINnum =", row[0], "Item = ", row[1], "Cost = ", row[2], "Qty Ordered=",userQty[j], "\n")
        prodCost = userQty[j] * row[2]
        print ("Total product cost is: ", (prodCost))
```

Maybe I have missed some occurrence, but it should become clear where you are stuck...

Update: When you want to do only one select, you have to generate a sequence of `?`, e.g. by

```
q = "(" + ",".join(["?" for x in userOrder]) + ")"
```

and append this to a query ending with `in`. You will also have to transform the `list` `userOrder` into a tuple. But then it becomes complicated to fiddle with the order of the result compared with the order of the entries in `prodQty`. Simply passing the array as a parameter and expect it to "expand" the `=` to an `in` will not work. If you do not want to completely change your program I would not try to go that way.